# Problem logging to website as administrator bug in environment hebrew support

Tags: python

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

cannot manage to login to the administrator Control panel

tried to search google for answers seems its hebrew support missing

UnicodeDecodeError
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/home/sce-admin/survey/app.py", line 242, in wrap
return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/sce-admin/survey/app.py", line 268, in wrap
return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/sce-admin/survey/app.py", line 328, in administratorMenu
return render_template('administratorMenu.html')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 135, in render_template
context, ctx.app)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 117, in _render
rv = template.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/home/sce-admin/survey/templates/administratorMenu.html", line 1, in top-level template code
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
File "/home/sce-admin/survey/templates/layout.html", line 19, in top-level template code
{% include 'includes/_messages.html' %}
File "/home/sce-admin/survey/templates/includes/_messages.html", line 4, in top-level template code
<div class="alert alert-{{ category }}">{{ message }}</div>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error.
To switch between the interactive traceback and the plaintext one, you can click on the "Traceback" headline. From the text traceback you can also create a paste of it. For code execution mouse-over the frame you want to debug and click on the console icon on the right side.
```

You can execute arbitrary Python code in the stack frames and there are some extra helpers available for introspection:

dump() shows all variables in the frame
dump(obj) dumps all that's known about the object

I expect there to be no errors as it works fine on other ubuntu environment seems like some hebrew support plugin missing?

Comment: have you tried adding `#encoding=utf-8` to the top of `app.py` ?

Comment: the odd part about it that it works fine on other environment with the same code, could it be that im missing some python support for hebrew in the linux environment for encoding?